# For loop in constexpr function fails to compile with MSVC 19.23

Tags: c++, for-loop, c++17, constexpr, compile-time

The following code compiles in Clang and GCC, but fails in MSVC.

```
template <typename... FieldsSequence>
struct S {
    static constexpr bool checkIdUniqueness()
    {
        using IdType = int;
        constexpr IdType fieldIds[sizeof...(FieldsSequence)]{ 0 };
        for (size_t i = 0; i < std::size(fieldIds) - 1; ++i)
        {
            if (fieldIds[i] > fieldIds[i + 1])
            {
                constexpr auto tmp = fieldIds[i];
                fieldIds[i] = fieldIds[i + 1];
                fieldIds[i + 1] = tmp;
            }
        }

        return true;
    }
};
```

The error message is:

```
expression did not evaluate to a constant
note: failure was caused by a read of a variable outside its lifetime
note: see usage of 'i'
```

Is there a way to make this work with all the three compilers? Ultimately, I need to bubble-sort the array to assert at compile time that all the values are unique.

https://godbolt.org/z/9XbP6-

Comment: What's `FieldsSequence`?

Comment: Unrelated to your problem, but technically you don't sort (not even bubble) your array. Bubble sort needs multiple passes over the container to "bubble" up the sorted values, commonly implemented using nested loops. And regarding the sorting, can't you use `std::sort`? And regarding the uniqueness, can't you use sets?

Comment: @StoryTeller: An abstract template type pack, see godbolt link for complete compilable sample.

Comment: @VioletGiraffe You should know by now that questions should be self-contained, and that your [mcve] needs enough context for us to understand it without going to external sites or asking about what symbols are. Please consider a refresh of [the help pages](http://stackoverflow.com/help), especially  [how to ask good questions](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), as well as [this question checklist](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2012/11/24/stack-overflow-question-checklist/).

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude: `std::sort` is not `constexpr` until C++20, and `std::set` not even then (AFAIK). If my code will work, I don't see why a second inner loop won't. Resulting in compile-time bubble-sorting. And then a separate for loop to check for uniqueness.

Comment: This code does not appear to work even in GCC or Clang when I actually instantiate it.  I get a number of errors, such as attempting to write to the `constexpr` value `fieldIds[i]`.

Comment: Another approach is to write this in the style of a functional program, with recursive `constexpr` templates and functions.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You overused `constexpr` declarations. For one, if `fieldIds` is declared `constexpr` then it's also const, and you can't mutate it. As for `tmp`, because it's declared `constexpr` the initializer must be a constant expression, but it can't be one really.

The correct approach is to remove `constexpr` from those declarations:

```
template <typename... FieldsSequence>
struct S {
    static constexpr bool checkIdUniqueness()
    {
        using IdType = int;
        IdType fieldIds[sizeof...(FieldsSequence)]{ 0 };
        for (size_t i = 0; i < std::size(fieldIds) - 1; ++i)
        {
            if (fieldIds[i] > fieldIds[i + 1])
            {
                auto tmp = fieldIds[i];
                fieldIds[i] = fieldIds[i + 1];
                fieldIds[i + 1] = tmp;
            }
        }

        return true;
    }
};
```

The function as a whole can still *be evaluated in a constant expression*, but there is no extra requirement on those variables now that can interfere with their declaration or usage.

Comment: Makes sense, but I was unsure if `constexpr` actually implies `const`, as in immutable even at compile time. Seems like C++ is missing another keyword, something like `compiletime`, which would be used instead of `constexpr` and could be combined with `const` as needed. Thanks for setting this straight for me.

Comment: One thing I still don't get: why can't `tmp` be `constexpr`?

Comment: @VioletGiraffe - Because now `fieldIds` isn't. Before it couldn't be because `i` isn't a constant expression. That's just the rules of the abstract machine.